# python pandas: passing in dataframe to df.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Long time user of this site but first time asking a question!  Thanks to all of the benevolent users who have been answering questions for ages :)

I have been using `df.apply` lately and ideally want to pass a dataframe into the `args` parameter to look something like so:  `df.apply(testFunc, args=(dfOther), axis = 1)`

My ultimate goal is to iterate over the dataframe I am passing in the `args` parameter and check logic against each row of the original dataframe, say  `df` , and return some value from  `dfOther` .  So say I have a function like this:

```
def testFunc(row, dfOther):
    for index, rowOther in dfOther.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == rowOther[0] and row['B'] == rowOther[1]:
            return dfOther.at[index, 'C']

df['OTHER'] = df.apply(testFunc, args=(dfOther), axis = 1)
```

My current understanding is that `args` expects a Series object, and so if I actually run this we get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

However before I wrote `testFunc` which only passes in a single dataframe, I had actually written `priorTestFunc`, which looks like this...  And it works!

```
def priorTestFunc(row, dfOne, dfTwo):
    for index, rowOne in dfOne.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == rowOne[0] and row['B'] == rowOne[1]:
            return dfTwo.at[index, 'C']

df['OTHER'] = df.apply(testFunc, args=(dfOne, dfTwo), axis = 1)
```

So to my dismay I have been coming into the habit of writing `testFunc` like so and it has been working as intended:

```
def testFunc(row, dfOther, _):
    for index, rowOther in dfOther.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == rowOther[0] and row['B'] == rowOther[1]:
            return dfOther.at[index, 'C']

df['OTHER'] = df.apply(testFunc, args=(dfOther, _), axis = 1)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could let me know why this would be the case and maybe errors that I will be prone to, or maybe another alternative for solving this kind of problem!!

EDIT:  As requested by the comment: My dfs generally look like the below.. They will have two matching columns and will be returning a value from the `dfOther.at[index, column]` I have considered `pd.concat([dfOther, df])` however I will be running an algorithm testing conditions on `df` and then updating it accordingly from specific values on `dfOther`(which will also be updating) and I would like  `df` to be relatively neat, as opposed to making a multindex and throwing just about everything in it.  Also I am aware `df.iterrows` is in general slow, but these dataframes will be about 500 rows at the max, so scalability isn't really a massive concern for me at the moment.

```
df
Out[10]: 
    A    B      C
0  foo  bur   6000
1  foo  bur   7000
2  foo  bur   8000
3  bar  kek   9000
4  bar  kek  10000
5  bar  kek  11000

dfOther
Out[12]: 
    A    B      C
0  foo  bur   1000
1  foo  bur   2000
2  foo  bur   3000
3  bar  kek   4000
4  bar  kek   5000
5  bar  kek   6000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\p2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4017, in apply
    if kwds or args and not isinstance(func, np.ufunc):
```

Here, `if kwds or args` is checking whether the length of `args` passed to `apply` is greater than 0. It is a common way to check if an iterable is empty:

```
l = []

if l:
    print("l is not empty!")
else:
    print("l is empty!")
```

> `l is empty!`

```
l = [1]

if l:
    print("l is not empty!")
else:
    print("l is empty!")
```

> `l is not empty!`

If you had passed a tuple to `df.apply` as `args`, it would return True and there wouldn't be a problem. However, Python does not interpret (df) as a tuple:

```
type((df))
Out[39]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

It is just a DataFrame/variable inside parentheses. When you type `if df`:

```
if df:
    print("df is not empty")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-c86da5a5f1ee>", line 1, in <module>
    if df:

  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\p2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 887, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

You get the same error message. However, if you use a comma to indicate that it'a tuple, it works fine:

```
if (df, ):
    print("tuple is not empty")

tuple is not empty
```

As a result, adding a comma to `args=(dfOther)` by making it a [singleton](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)  should solve the problem.

```
df['OTHER'] = df.apply(testFunc, args=(dfOther, ), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @ayhan for the well described and elegant answer.